# Define Chronology size to textwidth

Tags: pdftex, packages

I want to use the [chronology package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chronology) to make a nice timeline. However, I cannot get it to work at all. It seems to have a serious problem with the \textwidth and \linewidth commands, although the -outdated- [documentation](http://ctan.localhost.net.ar/macros/latex/contrib/chronology/chronology.pdf) explicitely states that this should be possible.

I keep getting the "Missing number, treated as zero ..." error.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}[3]{1990}{2000}{3ex}{\linewidth}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me when I correct the syntax: the last argument is optional and should be in square - not curly - brackets.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{chronology}[3]{1990}{2000}{3ex}[\linewidth]
\end{chronology}
\bigskip

\begin{chronology}*[5]{1764}{1800}{\textwidth}[12cm]
      \small
      \event{1789}{\color{blue}Declaration of the Rights of Man and of the Citizen}
      \event[1789]{1799}{\color{blue}French Revolution}
      \event{1793}{{\color{blue}Declaration of the Rights of Man and Citizen} | {\color{gray}\emph{The Age of Reason}}}
      \event[1765]{1783}{\color{purple}American Revolution}
      \event{1776}{{\color{purple}Declaration of Independence} | {\color{gray}\emph{Common Sense}}}
      \event{1791}{\color{gray}\emph{Rights of Man}}
      \event{1787}{\color{purple}Constitution}
      \event[1789]{1791}{\color{purple}Bill of Rights}
      \event{1795}{\color{gray}\emph{Agrarian Justice}}
\end{chronology}
\end{document}
```

[image: timelines]

I suspect that you want `{\linewidth}[3ex]` rather than `{3ex}[\linewidth]`, perhaps?

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are right. How do you know this, is there a documentation somewhere? In the old one I linked to above the arguments are different and there is nothing about chronology with a star.

Comment: @anjuta I copied one I made earlier ;). I think I probably just looked at the example file included in the package. If you open `example.pdf` alongside `example.tex`, you can more-or-less figure out what does what. The second timeline in the example file uses the star. As far as I can tell, there is no documentation as such and I don't remember reading any.